# How to change color of lable (name) in a highcharts series?

Tags: jquery, plugins, highcharts

I am using Highcharts  **type: 'line'**.

In my code i have this

```
series: [{
            name: 'Average Time Spent per Month',
            data: organ
        }]
```

I want to change color of this label

**Average Time Spent per Month**

I tried this

```
color : '#FFFFFF'
```

Which only changed color of the **series** .

When I tried this

```
labels:{
          style: {
                  color: '#FFFFFF'
                 }
       }
```

and

```
style: {
                  color: '#FFFFFF'
        }
```

Nothing changed.

I also read this documentation 
[Highcharts/Series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series)

But unable to find the information i need.

Comment: if possible provide us fiddle link

Comment: Please try this  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

Comment: I want to change  color of these text : Tokyo, London, NewYork, Berlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your codes inside setoptions

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Sample: [link 1](http://jsfiddle.net/cbhe9x17/5/)

updated: [link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/cbhe9x17/7/)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. This is not actually i wanted. I want to change the color of these text > Test1 ,Series1,Series 2

Comment: It Works!!  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome !! Happy coding